# Streaming a log file using ajax not working on second request

Tags: php, jquery, http-headers

I have a very big txt file log I need to stream to the browser. I have a PHP application running in the background that adds info to the log file as it does it's stuff. I would like a browser support to view the log in real time. The expected behavior is that on the first load it grabs the whole file content then will reload with the next 30kb and repeat. I have the initial request done but as soon as it tries to grab the next 30kb i get the following error:

```
An error occured :-(.
Reloading may help; no promises.
Uncaught Invalid integer accept-ranges: bytes
cache-control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0
content-disposition: inline; filename=log.txt
content-length: 5747975
content-range: bytes 0-5747975/5747976
content-transfer-encoding: binary
content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
date: Fri, 27 Nov 2020 17:46:54 GMT
last-modified: Fri, 27 Nov 2020 17:39:28 +0000
pragma: no-cache
server: LiteSpeed
status: 206
x-litespeed-cache-control: no-cache
x-powered-by: PHP/7.4.12
```

This is the PHP side streaming the txt file (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php#86244):

```
function smartReadFile($location, $filename, $mimeType='application/octet-stream')
{ 
  $size=filesize($location);
  $time=date('r',filemtime($location));

  if(!file_exists($location)) { header ("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    return;
  }
 
  $fm=@fopen($location,'rb');
  if(!$fm)
  { header ("HTTP/1.0 505 Internal server error");
    return;
  }
 
  $begin=0;
  $end=$size;
 
  if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
  { if(preg_match('/bytes=\h*(\d+)-(\d*)[\D.*]?/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], $matches))
    { $begin=intval($matches[0]);
      if(!empty($matches[1]))
        $end=intval($matches[1]);
    }
  }
 
  if($begin>0||$end<$size)
    header('HTTP/1.0 206 Partial Content');
  else
    header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK'); 
 
  header("Content-Type: $mimeType");
  header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
  header('Pragma: no-cache'); 
  header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
  header('Content-Length:'.($end-$begin));
  header("Content-Range: bytes $begin-$end/$size");
  header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$filename");
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
  header("Last-Modified: $time");
  header('Connection: close'); 
 
  $cur=$begin;
  fseek($fm,$begin,0);

  while(!feof($fm)&&$cur<$end&&(connection_status()==0))
  { print fread($fm,min(1024*16,$end-$cur));
    $cur+=1024*16;
  }
}
```

This is the javascript side doing the ajax request (https://github.com/ukhas/js-logtail)

```
(function () {

    var dataelem = "#data";
    var pausetoggle = "#pause";
    var scrollelems = ["html", "body"];
    
    var url = "?mod=log";
    var fix_rn = true;
    var load = 30 * 1024; /* 30KB */
    var poll = 1000; /* 1s */
    
    var kill = false;
    var loading = false;
    var pause = false;
    var reverse = true;
    var log_data = "";
    var log_file_size = 0;
    
    /* :-( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt */
    function parseInt2(value) {
        if(!(/^[0-9]+$/.test(value))) throw "Invalid integer " + value;
        var v = Number(value);
        if (isNaN(v))                 throw "Invalid integer " + value;
        return v;
    }
    
    function get_log() {
        if (kill | loading) return;
        loading = true;
    
        var range;
        var first_load;
        var must_get_206;
        if (log_file_size === 0) {
            /* Get the last 'load' bytes */
            range = "-" + load.toString();
            first_load = true;
            must_get_206 = false;
        } else {
            /* Get the (log_file_size - 1)th byte, onwards. */
            range = (log_file_size - 1).toString() + "-";
            first_load = false;
            must_get_206 = log_file_size > 1;
        }
    
        /* The "log_file_size - 1" deliberately reloads the last byte, which we already
         * have. This is to prevent a 416 "Range unsatisfiable" error: a response
         * of length 1 tells us that the file hasn't changed yet. A 416 shows that
         * the file has been trucnated */
    
        $.ajax(url, {
            dataType: "text",
            cache: false,
            headers: {Range: "bytes=" + range},
            success: function (data, s, xhr) {
                loading = false;
    
                var content_size;
    
                if (xhr.status === 206) {
                    var c_r = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Range");
                    if (!c_r)
                        throw "Server did not respond with a Content-Range";
    
                    log_file_size = parseInt2(c_r.split("/")[1]);
                    content_size = parseInt2(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders("Content-Length"));
                } else if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    if (must_get_206)
                        throw "Expected 206 Partial Content";   
                    content_size = log_file_size =
                            parseInt2(xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Length"));
                } else {
                    throw "Unexpected status " + xhr.status;
                }
    
                /* && data.length > load)
                    throw "Server's response was too long";*/
    
                var added = false;
    
                if (first_load) {
                    /* Clip leading part-line if not the whole file */
                    if (content_size < log_file_size) {
                        var start = data.indexOf("\n");
                        log_data = data.substring(start + 1);
                    } else {
                        log_data = data;
                    }
    
                    added = true;
                } else {
                    /* Drop the first byte (see above) */
                    log_data += data.substring(1);
    
                    if (log_data.length > load) {
                        var start = log_data.indexOf("\n", log_data.length - load);
                        log_data = log_data.substring(start + 1);
                    }
    
                    if (data.length > 1)
                        added = true;
                }
    
                if (added)
                    show_log(added);
                setTimeout(get_log, poll);
            },
            error: function (xhr, s, t) {
                loading = false;
    
                if (xhr.status === 416 || xhr.status == 404) {
                    /* 416: Requested range not satisfiable: log was truncated. */
                    /* 404: Retry soon, I guess */
    
                    log_file_size = 0;
                    log_data = "";
                    show_log();
    
                    setTimeout(get_log, poll);
                } else {
                    throw "Unknown AJAX Error (status " + xhr.status + ")";
                }
            }
        });
    }
    
    function scroll(where) {
        for (var i = 0; i < scrollelems.length; i++) {
            var s = $(scrollelems[i]);
            if (where === -1)
                s.scrollTop(s.height());
            else
                s.scrollTop(where);
        }
    }
    
    function show_log() {
        if (pause) return;
    
        var t = log_data;
    
        if (reverse) {
            var t_a = t.split(/\n/g);
            t_a.reverse();
            if (t_a[0] == "") 
                t_a.shift();
            t = t_a.join("\n");
        }
    
        if (fix_rn)
            t = t.replace(/\n/g, "\r\n");
    
        $(dataelem).text(t);
        if (!reverse)
            scroll(-1);
    }
    
    function error(what) {
        kill = true;
    
        $(dataelem).text("An error occured :-(.\r\n" +
                         "Reloading may help; no promises.\r\n" + 
                         what);
        scroll(0);
    
        return false;
    }
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.onerror = error;
    
        /* If URL is /logtail/?noreverse display in chronological order */
        var hash = location.search.replace(/^\?/, "");
        if (hash == "noreverse")
            reverse = false;
    
        /* Add pause toggle */
        $(pausetoggle).click(function (e) {
            pause = !pause;
            $(pausetoggle).text(pause ? "Unpause" : "Pause");
            show_log();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    
        get_log();
    });
    
})();
```

As soon as it gets to the second request with a 206 I get the following error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I changed my code a lot and sometimes simpler is better ...

Js code looks like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#data").load("index.php?mod=log&do=refresh");
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    (function () {
        $("#data").load("index.php?mod=log");
    }), 1000);
    function ScrollDiv(){

        if(document.getElementById('data').scrollTop<(document.getElementById('data').scrollHeight-document.getElementById('data').offsetHeight)){-1
              document.getElementById('data').scrollTop=document.getElementById('data').scrollTop+1
              }
        else {/*document.getElementById('data').scrollTop=0;*/}
     }
     
     setInterval(ScrollDiv, 1)
});
```